# Exe created on virtual server with PyInstaller fails to execute

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, pyinstaller

I have created an exe using Pyinstaller with python `virtualenv`, I am **able to do this in the normal python environment** without any problems, however when creating it on a virtual server the exe once created fails to execute (open). 
I have created the exe with the following debug options,

`Scripts\pyinstaller --debug=all --log-level=DEBUG`

There is nothing in the log that indicates any specific error.
However when I try to open the exe, In the Tracing process while clicking through the different windows, the following message pops up:

[image]
'

[49852]: LOADER: Error activating the context: ActivateActCtx: 
An Attempt to set the process default activation context failed because the process default activation context as already set.

It allows you to click "OK" through the rest of the messages and then:

[image]

I have tried to trace and debug and find the error, however I have not had much success, there are no missing modules or errors in the log.

I am using Python 3.7.4

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you creating the exe on the virtual server?

Comment: Hi Syntax, yes I am, I followed the (https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/) guidelines to create the virtual server. Then I installed all the packages I required and used pyinstaller to create the exe.

Comment: I have found a warning message: 50415 WARNING: Hidden import "distutils.command.build_ext" not found!

Comment: However I am not sure if this is the issue.

Comment: I fixed the disutils, so the WARNING message doesn't come anymore by changing the hook in the pre_find_module_path. So now I have no Warnings.. but the application still fails to open.

Comment: The first error message is the actual error, the second one is for pyinstaller itself which is not relevant. I think it is about your code. Can you provide a minimal example of your code?